# Use and meaning of data: { get_param: 'value' } in jQuery ajax + JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I am parsing generated json with jquery $.ajax but there is one option that I dont understand. I saw it in some examples and tried to look for at jquery.com but still not sure about it:

this option is:

```
data: { get_param: 'value' }
```

which is used like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'http://example/functions.php', 
                data: { get_param: 'value' }, //why we shell use that in that case?
                success: function (data) { 
                                    var names = data
                    $('#cand').html(data);
                }
          });
```

I know that "**data:**" is what sent to the server but parsing JSON I thought i don't send but retrieve from server with GET type. And the next part "**get_param: 'value'**"
 does not make sense to me in that case either, could anyone please explain when and what for and in what cases it shell be used?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that "data" is what sent to the server

Yes. If `data` is an object, it gets serialized to an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string and then placed in the query string or request body as appropriate for the request type (GET/POST).

jQuery does all the escaping necessary for this.

(It also, by default, collapses nested data structures (you don't have any in your example) into PHP-style by adding `[]` to key names).

> but parsing JSON

JSON is not involved (unless the server responds with some).

> when and what for and in what cases it shell be used

Whenever you want to pass data to the server rather than requesting a static URI.

Comment: so I could skip that line "data: { get_param: 'value' }" if I only want to parse the provided url and place it in DOM on success as I want without sending it to server. Am I correct?

Comment: @Alex — Yes. That would be "requesting a static URI".

Comment: "Whenever you want to pass data to the server rather than requesting a static URI." what does it exactly mean? 

get_param: 'value',

what is value for, it is a keyword or it works only in this case?
And what about get_param? It is a javascript keyword?

Comment: @Matto — If you have a new question, you can [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but you should really read an introductory JavaScript tutorial first as object literal syntax is one of the very fundamentals of the language.

Answer (score 1):

You don't send JSON (usually), you send simple GET or POST HTTP parameters. They are given to the `ajax` method in an object literal usually, but you could have used the string `"getparam=value"`, too. If you provide an object, jQuery will do the parameter-serialisation and URL-encoding for you - they're sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

To cite from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **data** (`Object`, `String`)
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   `processData` option to prevent this automatic processing. *Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs*. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the `traditional` setting.